# How To Use SharePoint 2013 REST API In Order To Remove Contribute Permission On List Item

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to break the roleinheritance with the SharePoint REST API on a single list item. This can be done using http:///_api/Web/Lists(guid'listid')/Items(itemid)/breakroleinheritance(false).

I am using false as parameter in order not to copy the permissions from the list.

The next goal is to assign reader permission to couple of groups and users (I have the Ids of the users and the groups)

But the next step is more complicated. I must use POST requests in order to update/add permissions and cannot find examples on this.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have found the answer here:http://spsite.pro/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=22

Comment: Updated Link http://spsite.pro/Blog/Post/3/SharePoint-2013-REST-API-%E2%80%93-How-to-set-Unique-Permissions-%28Item-Level-Permissions%29

Comment: Here is my article  http://enjoymicrosoftsharepoint.blogspot.in/2016/06/how-to-set-item-level-permissions-using.html